# How to add/delete entries in xml maps using XSL 3.0

Tags: arrays, dictionary, xslt

What would be xsl 3.0 way in order to add `<string key="name">abc</string>` to the map after `<string key="value">1001</string>`?
What about deleting array element e.g. `<number>1050.0</number>`?
Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
  <array key="content">
    <map key="Details">>
      <number key="id">70805774</number>
      <string key="value">1001</string>
      <array key="position">
        <number>1004.0</number>
        <number>288.0</number>
        <number>1050.0</number>
        <number>324.0</number>
      </array>
    </map>
  </array>
</map>
```

Comment: With that representation as XML it is simply a question of adding an element and deleting an element to that sample. Have you tried anything? Can you show us your effort?

Comment: I don't think your `array` can contain a `<map key="Details">` with a key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML to XML transformation requiring a few changes is usually done with the identity transformation as the base template (declared in XSLT 3 as `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>`) and then by adding templates for the changes you want to make e.g. add an element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="string[@key = 'value'][. = '1001']">
      <xsl:next-match/>
      <string key="name">abc</string>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93nwMo6

or delete one with `<xsl:template match="array[@key = 'position']/number[. = 1050]"/>` : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93nwMo6/1

You can the freely combine various changes by adding more templates:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="string[@key = 'value'][. = '1001']">
      <xsl:next-match/>
      <string key="name">abc</string>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="array[@key = 'position']/number[. = 1050]"/>
  
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93nwMo6/2

Another approach would be to treat the data as XPath 3.1 maps and arrays and use the functions on those types; an intermediary result (the input sample you posted first needs to be corrected to have the `key` attribute on the `map` removed) would be:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence
      select="let $map := . => xml-to-json() => parse-json(),
                  $content := $map?content,
                  $contentMap := $content?1,
                  $newContentMap := $contentMap => map:put('name', 'abc'),
                  $newContentMap := $newContentMap => map:put('position', array:remove($contentMap?position, 3))
              return $map => map:put('content', array:put($content, 1, $newContentMap))"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93nwMo6/3

if you want to get back to the XML representation you can use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence
      select="let $map := . => xml-to-json() => parse-json(),
                  $content := $map?content,
                  $contentMap := $content?1,
                  $newContentMap := $contentMap => map:put('name', 'abc'),
                  $newContentMap := $newContentMap => map:put('position', array:remove($contentMap?position, 3)),
                  $map := $map => map:put('content', array:put($content, 1, $newContentMap))
              return $map => serialize(map { 'method' : 'json' }) => json-to-xml()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93nwMo6/4

The order of "object"/map items is not defined/preserved with XDM maps.

Comment: Both of them worked fine for me. I decided in favor of first approach. I omitted value  `[. = '1001']` part in match because of its dynamic change nature. I've worked through the both examples by using `xsl:comments` to log the midsteps. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<xsl:template match="string[key='value']">
   <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
   <string key="value">1001</string>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="array/number[3]"/>
```

Assuming the correct namespace declarations.

Comment: Thanks, but the StackOverflow convention is to mark the answer as accepted by clicking the tick/check mark next to the question - that's a better guide for people searching the site than a "thankyou" comment.